# break/stop numbered lists from continuing in the next table cell [Word 2013]

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm having some issues with word when I make numbered lists that are located within several tables and cells.

Word automatically continues from from previous number in the list even if it is in a new cell and also a new table. Looks almost like this.

TABLE1
- Cell1 1. Text. 2. Text. 3. Text.
- Cell2 4. Text. 5. Text.

TABLE2 -Cell1 6. Text.

Is there any way to force Word to start from 1. when I begin in a new cell/table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked for just two more seconds. Found the answer in "Home -> Numbering -> Set numbering value".

Here I can change the starting value of my numbered list, so problem solved.

[image: "Home -> Numbering -> Set numbering value]